# Likelihod ratio test: $f_0(x)=2x$ vs $f_1(x)=3x^2$ : $2n$ degree of freedom?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Let $\left\{ X_i \right \}$ be an $n$-sample with pdf $f$.
Show that the likelihood ratio test statistic for
\begin{align}
H_0 &: f(x) = 2x \\
H_1 &: f(x)= 3x^2
\end{align}
has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.

The likelihood ratio test statistic is
$$
\lambda = \frac{\prod f_0(x_i)}{\prod f_1(x_i)} = 
\frac{(2/3)^n}{t^n},
$$
with $t=\prod x_i$.
Then I should show
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} -2\ln \lambda \stackrel{d}= \chi^2(2n).
$$
How can the degree of freedom be $2n$?
I don't see any parameter in $H_0$ and $H_1$, to apply the theorem which says
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} -2\ln \lambda \stackrel{d}= \chi^2(\#\Theta_1-\#\Theta_0).
$$

Comment: $\lambda$ does not seem to have $\chi^2$ distribution under either $H_0$ or $H_1$. Probably you want to show that statement asymptotically.

Comment: @passerby51 Thanks, I meant asymptotically but didn't write clearly. I tried to copy a proof on the asymptotics of $\lambda$, but all the proof I know makes reference to the parameter space $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_0$.

Comment: The statement is still not quite correct. The RHS of your limit ($\chi^2(2n)$) depends on $n$ which shouldn't. Probably you want to show that $-2 \ln \lambda_n - Y_n$ goes to zero in probability, where $Y_n \sim \chi^2(2n)$ is some sequence of random variables. I am still not quite sure this is true. Are you sure you are not missing anything in the problem?

Comment: @passerby51 I think everything of the problem is here. I will try to find such a sequence $Y_n$. I tried to view the LRT as a goodness-of-fit test with $n$ cells in $H_0$ and $2n$ cells in $H_1$ ($max(f_0(X_i),f_1(X_i))$). Then the degree of freedom is $2n-n=n$.

Comment: Asked and answer on [statSE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51270/21186). @passerby51 the trick is that $-ln X_i$ has an exponential distribution under $H_0$, that is a $\chi^2$ with $2$ degrees of freedom.